# Angular 2 assignment issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to assign a formatted value, the below code is woking fine

```
export class AppComponent {
  public urlObj = this._urlService.get('GET_CLIENT_ID');
  url = this._urlService.formatURL('root', this.urlObj.URL);
  constructor(private _urlService: UrlService) {
  }
 }
```

But when I try to directly change urlObj.URL its not working like

```
export class AppComponent {
  public urlObj = this._urlService.get('GET_CLIENT_ID');
  this.urlObj.URL = this._urlService.formatURL('root', this.urlObj.URL);
  constructor(private _urlService: UrlService) {
  }
}
```

It is saying `Unexpected token at this.urlObj`

Comment: You can't use `this` outside of class methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_urlService` is initialized at constructor level. Try doing the assignment operation inside it:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public urlObj; 

  constructor(private _urlService: UrlService) {
   this._urlService.get('GET_CLIENT_ID');
   this.urlObj.URL = this._urlService.formatURL('root', this.urlObj.URL);
  }
```